# how to fetch columns in latest version of php?

Tags: php, mysqli

my database have a tables named students and its contains id, student name, course etc. information and I want to fetch all the information of specific column by id and store it in a variable.

for example, if I want to get id (roll no.) 5 student information and echo it on screen or store it in variable then how to do it?

Comment: It's just the same as it was in previous versions of PHP, with the exception of not being able to use the old-style `mysql_query()` and other similar functions. Use mysqli or PDO to connect to the database and run your query to retrieve the data, then retrieve it and display it. What specific problem have you had with the code you've tried? There are plenty of tutorials around for this, just steer clear of any that use the old functions, or don't use prepared statements.